# Arrangements of symbols with constraints

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Symbols : $$1 , 2 , 3, 4 , a,b,c,d  $$

Constraints :[$x<y$ means $x$ comes before $y$ in the arrangement]

- $1 < 2 < 3 < 4 $
- $a < b < c < d$
- $2 < c$

Find the number of arrangements of the given symbols that satisfy all the  constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the third constraint, it's a simple 8-choose-4 - pick which positions are for letters, then label the numbers and letters in the required order. The final constraint breaking possibilities (with $c<2$) can be counted in two cases, $d<2$ and $2<d$, and then subtracted from the total:

- $d<2$: allocate four letters into two categories ($x<1$ and $1<x$), stars&bars $\to$ 5-choose-1
- $2<d$: allocate three letters into two categories, stars&bars $\to$ 4-choose-1, and multiply by 3 positions for d

Comment: What about c<1 and 1<c ?[with c<2 assumed].

Comment: that's covered already; note that c could go either side of 1 in the cases discussed. I'll update again...

Comment: If d<2 ,then the arrangement becomes {abcd}234 ,with '1' in any of the 5 spaces in the curly bracket["5 choose 1" matches].
If d>2 then the arrangement becomes {abc}2{34} with '1' in any of the 4 spaces and 'd' in any of the 3 spaces [matches your interpretation ].
So, the answer becomes 70-5-12 = 53 arrangements .
Is this correct ?

Comment: I am still sceptical whether this is correct because this was a question with following four choices 2,70,7&12 . Though I    converted it from this question : http://i.imgur.com/phZG1u0.jpg

Comment: Hmm, I don't understand enough of the background to that "original" question to say whether they are equivalent or not. But as posed, I'm confident in the answer we have here.

Answer (score 0):

hint: fix 1,2,3,4 and treat spaces between them as gaps. In how many ways can you fill these 
gaps such that $c,d$ are strictly after 2 (you'll need a gap between 2 and c) ? There can be more than 1 gap between 2 numbers.

EDIT: think about it as $1_ _2_ _ _ _3_ _ _ _4_ _ _ _$. In how many ways can you fill in these gaps?

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines but then chickened out. Let me try again, though a full fledged answer is well appreciated . Thanks. Btw, I think your answer misses the constraint that a<b<c<d. How would you incorporate this constraint in your model ?

Comment: Why is there no gap before 1 ?

Comment: Yeah forgot them. Without the $c>2$ constraint the solution should have been $\binom{20}{4}$ because all you need to do is select 4 positions and divide through $4!$ because only order abcd is admissable

Comment: I am not sure. Too many overlapping cases makes it complicated. I would love it if you could see whether the accepted answer is correct because it seems to be very short and correct too. Thanks.